# "New hardware supports is... " button, will this change my 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS?

Tags: 12.04

When I go to update my Toshiba Laptop running 12.04LTS I see an icon saying "New Hardware Support is Available" does this upgrade me from 12.04 to 14.04?

I do NOT want this to happen, as some of the software I need doesn't run in 14.04, if someone can tell me with 100% certainty what happens when I click that button I'd be extremely grateful.

Here is my kernel info if that helps at all:

3.11.0-26-generic #45~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:02:35 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: It might be talking about the new hardware enablement stack  12.04.5

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about the stack, the "upgrade" spooked me a little, I couldn't figure out if it would stay the same version, but it did.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu version updates will make it clear that it is a version update instead of an ordinary update, so no unless it says anything regarding 14.04

Comment: Updated! Thx for the fast reply, I appreciate it.